# modulus of exponential complex numbers.

Tags: real-analysis

how one can find the modulus of such functions such as 
$$ \large|e^{e^{ime^{i\theta}}}| , |e^{ime^{i\theta}}| $$ where $m>0$ and $m$ is real.

i was trying to evaluate the above two .. but confused so much with $e$

I know that $|e^{i\theta}|$=1,

and tried the second one but i am not sure about it.
i got $$|e^{ime^{i\theta}}|=e^{-m\sin{\theta}}$$

can anyone help me in solving both the two. ??

Answer (score 1):

One has $|e^{x+iy}|=e^x$ where $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$.

So $i me^{i\theta}=im (\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta})=-m\sin{\theta}+im \cos{\theta}$ and

$$e^{im e^{i\theta}}=e^{-m\sin{\theta}}e^{im \cos{\theta}}=e^{-m\sin{\theta}}\left(\cos(m\cos{\theta})+i\sin(m\cos{\theta})\right)$$

Therefore

$$\begin{align}|e^{im e^{i\theta}}|=&e^{-m\sin{\theta}}\\|e^{e^{im e^{i\theta}}}|=&e^{\cos(m\theta)e^{-m\sin{\theta}}}\end{align}$$

Comment: is that so simple :O ???  are you sure  ??? i dont know , i am confused with an extra $e$

Comment: let me wait for some votes or more answers ...!!!

Comment: Let me correct the second one

Comment: Okay I am waiting for that .:)

Comment: Done now let me edit it better

Comment: Yeah.. that what I was getting.. thanks for confirming.:)